# Express promise chain error

Tags: javascript, mongodb, rest, api, express

I've written a simple express.js server that handles REST API requests and fetches data from a MongoDB database. When I make a GET request to a specific endpoint ("localhost:8081/api/getUserData"), the promise chain doesn't work the way I want it to, and I still don't understand.

This is the error I get:
"[TypeError: Cannot read property 'db' of undefined]"

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var rp = require("request-promise");
var cors = require('cors');

// use it before all route definitions
app.use(cors({ origin: '*' }));

/********************** REST API FUNCTIONS **********************/
app.get('/api/getUserData', function (req, res, next) {
  var context = {};
  console.log("in api getUserData")
  context.db_url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
  openDatabaseConnection(context)
    .then(getAllUserLocations)
    .then(closeDatabaseConnection)
    .then(function (context) {
      res.send(context.userLocations)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("ERROR :");
      console.log(error);
    })
})
/********************** END REST API FUNCTIONS **********************/

function getAllUserLocations(context) {
  context.db.collection("test").find().toArray().then(function (err, result) {
    console.log("Received from db: " + result.length + " objects");
    context.userLocations = result;
    return context;
  });
}

function openDatabaseConnection(context) {
  console.log("Opening DB connection...");
  return MongoClient.connect(context.db_url)
    .then(function (db) {
      console.log("DB connection opened.");
      context.db = db;
      return context;
    })
}

function closeDatabaseConnection(context) {
  console.log("Closing DB connection");
  return context.db.close()
    .then(function () {
      console.log("DB connection closed");
      return context;
    })
}

/********************** STARTING SERVER **********************/
var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port
  console.log("Githex server listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

Any help would be appreciated, and even more with an explanation because I don't understand what I've done wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: As `context` is defined as an object with just a `db_url` property, it doesn't have a `db` property when you use it in your `getAllUserLocations` function

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't it. I've removed from the code I provided another api request handler that works, without specifying the 'db' property. I just tried adding a db property before the promise chain but it doesn't solve it either..

Comment: You're right, the error indicates that `context` is undefined in one of your functions, and it can't *"read property 'db' of undefined"*, and it probably comes with a line number and more specific info as to where.

Comment: For instance, `getAllUserLocations()` doesn't really return anything, it needs to be `return context.db.collection(...` assuming that function also returns a promise.

Comment: Yep, I added "return context.db" etc and that solved the problem but now another one's come up ^^, I'll try to solve that one now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just like @adeneo mentioned on the first comment, you are missing the db property. Look at your first function:

```
app.get('/api/getUserData', function (req, res, next) {
  var context = {};
  console.log("in api getUserData")
  context.db_url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
  openDatabaseConnection(context)
    .then(getAllUserLocations)
    .then(closeDatabaseConnection)
    .then(function (context) {
      res.send(context.userLocations)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("ERROR :");
      console.log(error);
    })
});
```

Now going through the lines within this function:

1. You setup context as an empty object
2. You added a db_url property onto the object, so far you have

   ```
   context = {db_url: "mongodb://localhost:27017/test}
   ```
3. You pass the context object into the openDatabaseConnection function
4. Within the openDatabaseConnection function, you return a context object. This new returned object doesn't get set anywhere, it just gets returned and never used. You want to call the getuserlocation() function with that returned value.

So instead of just calling

```
.then(getAllUserConnection)
```

I would do

```
.then(function(context){getAllUserConnection(context);})
```

That should make use of the returned value and make sure you are using it.